# Withdrawing funds from contract that was not saved

Tags: solidity

I deployed a contract successfully and was able to fund it.  I was attempting to withdraw the ETH from the contract and my computer crashed.  Now when I go back to remix and select the file and go to deploy and run transactions, I get a "currently you have no contract instances to interact with"

I have tried to paste in the contract address in the field "load contract from address" but nothing happens.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Where was the contract deployed? The default Remix environment is Javascript VM is a temporary blockchain contained in the browser. If you want the contract to persist a browser restart you could use a public testnet like rinkeby, goerli or ropsten, a private testnet.